# How can I find formula of the function of this graph?

Tags: functions

I want to plot the graph in this picture, but I don't know formula of the function. I tried

```
 f[x_] := a x^9 + b x^8 + c x^7 + d x^6 + e x^5 + n x^4 + g x^3 + 
   h x^2 + k x + l ;
NSolve[{f[-2] == -2, f[2] == 2, f[4] == 4, f[0] == 6, f[1.5] == 3, 
  f'[0] == 0, f'[2.5] == 0, f'[1.5] == 0, f[2.5] == 1.5, 
  f'[1.2] == 0}, {a, b, c, d, e, n, g, h, k, l}, Reals]
```

I got

> {{a -> 0.23626, b -> -2.61292, c -> 9.81292, d -> -9.83145, 
>     e -> -26.1737, n -> 76.7269, g -> -67.1827, h -> 16.1222, k -> 0., 
>     l -> 6.}}

But the result don't exactly.

How can I find formula of the function of this graph?

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts about the inflexion point within $(1,2)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can extract the data from the picture ,then use the "FindFormula" to find formula of the function.(It is difficult to extract data directly through image processing, so I erased interference in the picture firstly) .

[image]

```
imgdat = Sort[ImageValuePositions[Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize[IMG], 1]];
dat = ({Rescale[#1, MinMax[imgdat[[;; , 1]]], {-2.1, 4.4}], Rescale[#2, MinMax[imgdat[[;; , 2]]], {-2.7, 6.4}]} & @@@ imgdat);
fits = FindFormula[dat, x, 1, "Score" ]
Show[ListPlot[dat], 
 Plot[First@fits, {x, -2.1, 4.4}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

maybe help.

Comment: Another approach is used here https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/120057-Can-We-Get-An-Exact-Curve-Fitting-Line .

Comment: @jiaoeyuhushu Where can I put my picture?

Comment: If my picture has name is pic.PNG, how to put it in your code?

Comment: @toandhsp RemoveAlphaChannel[pic.PNG]  or  Save as pic.JPG

Comment: How  I input pic.JPG? Where the command contain pic.JPG?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean,Run the code first :IMG = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sUmu.jpg"]

Comment: Yes. I don't know Import my picture.

Comment: Drag into notebook directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65367/discussion-between-toandhsp-and-jiaoeyushushu).